# Proxmox: Routing traffic between VPN and guest network

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, routing, proxmox

I have a Proxmox setup on an internal corporate network that hosts multiple VMs. Users connect to the network via a VPN connection that allows access to a gateway machine running Windows and from there they can SSH into the respective VM. The setup is as follows:

1. VPN IP address is in the range (IP address that is assigned to VPN clients): `10.81.234.10/24`
2. Gateway Windows host IP address (Gateway/Bastion host): `192.168.2.0/24`
3. Proxmox Node address: `192.168.1.250`
4. Proxmox guest IP range: `192.168.1.0/24`

When a user connects to the VPN, a static IP route is added to Gateway host as follows:

```
/sbin/ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 10.81.234.5
```

On the Bastion/Gateway node, traceroute shows the route to reach `192.168.1.10` (one of the guest VMs:

```
Tracing route to 192.168.1.10 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.2.253
  2    15 ms    14 ms    12 ms  192.168.1.253
```

What I would like to do is somehow reach the guests VMs directly from the user's machine over the VPN i.e. route traffic from `10.81.234.0/24` network to `192.168.1.0/24` network. The idea is to allow users to SSH directly from their laptops to guest VMs.

Is this possible by just changing routing configuration?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The route table on the client side would need to be updated to send 192.168.1.0/24 to its VPN interface.  If the VPN is a full tunnel instead of a split tunnel this is an unnecessary step since all traffic is already pushed through the VPN.

Getting that traffic to the VPN server is the first step, however Windows won't route packets unless Routing and Remote Access (RAS) is on. I'm not sure what VPN software you're using on the Windows host (is it native RAS?)

Some VPN servers will give the option to NAT or route client traffic.  The easiest might be to NAT if that's an option.